# Grails/GORM -- Using 'hasMany' to map an association to an entire class hierarchy

Tags: grails, groovy, uml, grails-orm, class-diagram

I have the following Class Diagram for a grails application called `Projects`:

[image: enter image Class Diagrammhere]

Now I want to create the actual domain classes in grails. But I have an issue with that: I don't know how to map the associations in a "best practice" way. This is best explained by the example of a code implementation of the `Project` domain class:

```
package com.pm.projects

class Project {

    static hasMany = [contracts:Contract, customerContracts:CustomerContract, partnerContracts: PartnerContract]

    String property1
    Integer property2
    Date property3
         .
         .
         .
    TypeN propertyN

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I have the feeling that it is bad practice to include all contract subclasses in the `hasMany` map, because in an UML Class Diagram, subclasses inherit associations of their superclasses. Therefore, from a logical data model point of view, I feel like it would be leaner, clearer just to code:

```
static hasMany = [contracts:Contract]
```

Although this felt as the right approach in theory for myself, it turned out to make certain manipulation techniques of the data unavailable. For instance,

```
pro = Project.get(params.id)
ProPaconList = pro?.partnercontracts
ProCuconList = pro?.customercontracts
```

to create two lists of contracts, one for partnercontracts and another one for customercontracts.

Is it possible to achieve a similar result without including the subclasses in the `hasMany` map? And even if yes, the more general Question would be: Can hasMany maps be compared to associations of UML Class Diagramms in a way that it is bad practice to "connect" a class not only with another independent class but also with this other class' subclasses?

I failed to find any information on this topic online, which is a shame because I am very interested in accurate data modelling following best practice and common conventions, not only trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map just like you felt right:

```
static hasMany = [contracts:Contract]
```

Then, if you want to get just the contracts of certain type, you can just create a method on the Project domain class to do so:

```
class Project {
    static hasMany = [contracts:Contract]

    def findPartnerContracts(){
        return contracts.findAll { contract ->
            contract.instanceOf( PartnerContract )
        }
    }
}

def pro = Project.get(params.id)
def proPaconList = pro?.findPartnerContracts()
```

I am not sure if this is a best practice, but... it is one  way to do it.

Be careful with hasMany associations. If your collection tends to get big overtime, you might have performance issues. Take a look at [this presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance) by [Burt Beckwith](http://burtbeckwith.com/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. This is the kind of solution I was looking for. I voted up your answer; however, I am not sure if this is "best practice" or at least a recommended way by an acknowledged source, which is why I didn't mark your answer as "accepted answer", although it was still helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would say that a 'best practice' is very much dependent on how your application will work, and the context that it is in. You could take either approach - I think the choice depends on answers to a few questions:

- How many contracts will there be? As Felipe says, you could have performance problems by searching a single association.
- Do you often want to separate contracts into types? If so, your approach may be better - even storing them on different tables. Be aware that if you store sub-classes on the same table, GORM/Hibernate will add a discriminator column so it can discriminate the types, which adds a small complication to the retrieval.
- You might also consider doing explicit queries to retrieve only want you want from the database directly, instead of relying on GORMs association queries. If you had a lot of data, and wanted some kind of ordering or a subset, it may be better to do explicit queries (encapsulated in methods on Project) to get what you want.

So these are just a few things you might want to think about to decide what  your 'best practice' is.

BTW, a small comment on your class diagram: since both Contract sub-classes reference a Timesheet, you could move that association up to Contract, and let them both inherit it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by seperating into types often? The customer and partner contracts are again specialized in three different customer and partner contract types. Is that what you mean? Also, what do you mean by "my approach", including only the "contract" in the hasMany map? Could you explain in detail when I should use table for hierarchy or table for subclass?

Comment: By ' your approach', I mean the way you specified separate Partner and Customer associations. This can be useful if you always want to separate access to these distinct types - it's quicker and simpler than having a single association and searching. This is what I mean by 'often wanting to separate contracts into types'. Without knowing the details of your application it's hard to say whether you should use a single table for Contracts and sub-classes, or a table for each, but  unless you have *a lot* of data, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: In situations where it's hard to make a decision because the trade-offs aren't clear, I generally go with the simplest solution, which in this case is a single table for all Contract sub-classes